# SSHFS in fstab requests password even though user connects fine using keyfile

Tags: sshfs

I have added a following line in fstab:

```
sshfs#root@1.2.3.4:/root/dir /home/dir fuse.sshfs defaults,_netdev 0 0
```

When I try to mount it with `mount -a`, I get a password request, even though I've added `id_rsa.pub` of `root` to `authorized_keys` of the server to connect to, and when I run `ssh root@1.2.3.4` as root, I don't get asked for password.

Also, when I run:

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other root@1.2.3.4:/root/dir /home/dir
```

It connects fine. I'm doing this as `root` user, so the problem obviously isn't that ssh runs as root, but ssh key is of some user.

Why doesn't sshfs use the key?

Comment: Title says does not request password, body says does. Can you fix the question to make it clear.

Comment: @richard, sorry, indeed, the title was wrong. Thanks

Comment: This should not be closed as "can't be reproduced". The question clearly shows the `sshfs#` prefix (which the answer states is the issue). Prefixing the line with `sshfs#` is common for fuse mounts, and is in numerous documents on the web: https://goo.gl/b1d6Gd http://goo.gl/ilhqjw

Comment: @Patrick: Well, I guess they closed it because the problem "went away when a typo was fixed". My understanding of that close reason is that it's meant for monumentally stupid typos, like "Why is the system saying `muont not found`?" I believe that this solution to this problem ***is*** likely to help future readers, so I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the `sshfs#` part in `fstab`, apparently it's passed to ssh as-is, and it presumably searches for id_rsa of that missing user. After I've removed `sshfs#` it worked fine.